# Color tags based on regex emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using `org-mode` and I want all my tags beginning with `@` to be colored in blue.
Is it possible and how to do it ?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following answer uses the built-in mechanisms of `org-mode`.  The variable `org-tag-faces` accepts a regexp for the tag, which is the `car` of the cons cell.  The function `org-set-tag-faces` sets a global variable `org-tags-special-faces-re`, which combines the tags of the aforementioned cons cell(s).  The global variable `org-tags-special-faces-re` is used by `org-font-lock-add-tag-faces` to `re-search-forward` through the `org-mode` buffer -- locating the matching tags and applying the appropriate face based on the function `org-get-tag-face`.  The original version of the function `org-get-tag-face` looked for an exact match of the tag found (i.e., the `key` argument to the function `assoc`).  The revised version of `org-get-tag-face` adds an additional `key` search for `@.*` and returns the proper face if the `key` is found -- this is necessary because the tag itself will usually look something like `@home` or `@office`, whereas our context regexp is `@.*`.

```lisp
(require 'org)

(add-to-list 'org-tag-faces '("@.*" . (:foreground "cyan")))

;; Reset the global variable to nil, just in case org-mode has already beeen used.
(when org-tags-special-faces-re
  (setq org-tags-special-faces-re nil))

(defun org-get-tag-face (kwd)
  "Get the right face for a TODO keyword KWD.
If KWD is a number, get the corresponding match group."
  (if (numberp kwd) (setq kwd (match-string kwd)))
  (let ((special-tag-face (or (cdr (assoc kwd org-tag-faces))
                              (and (string-match "^@.*" kwd)
                                   (cdr (assoc "@.*" org-tag-faces))))))
    (or (org-face-from-face-or-color 'tag 'org-tag special-tag-face)
        'org-tag)))
```

Comment: Wow, thank's a lot, that's cool even if I don't understand everything (my knowledges about lisp and emacs-lisp are very limited ^^). Now, say that I want to do the same with other regex, can you explain me (in the simpliest way) how do I do ?

Comment: The `car` of each cons cell of `org-tag-faces` is by its very nature a regexp, which gets processed into something that eventually looks like this:  `":\\(@.*\\|TOP\\|HIGH\\|MEDIUM\\|LOW\\|NEGATIVE):"`  So, it is already set up to work with `regexp` out-of-the-box.  The change that needs to be made is how `org-get-tag-face` locates a match within `org-tag-faces`.  You could add additional entries to `org-tag-faces` with your regexp, and add additional entries to `org-get-tag-face` -- e.g., just above `(cdr (assoc "@.*" org-tag-faces))`.

Comment: For example, `(add-to-list 'org-tag-faces '("MYREGEX" . (:foreground "red")))` and just *above* `(cdr (assoc "@.*" org-tag-faces))` in `org-get-tag-face`, insert `(cdr (assoc "MYREGEX" org-tag-faces))`  The function `assoc` is using `equal` to find an exact key match.

Comment: I changed `(cdr (assoc "@.*" org-tag-faces))` to `(and (string-match "^@.*" kwd) (cdr (assoc "@.*" org-tag-faces)))` to ensure that `kwd` is indeed a context tag before testing to see if a context tag regexp is a `car` of one of the cons cells that make up `org-tag-faces`.  This will be important if you decide to add additional regexp to `org-get-tag-face`; e.g., adding an additional `(and (string-match "MYREGEX" kwd) (cdr (assoc "MYREGEX" org-tag-faces)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `font-lock-add-keywords`, for example, evaluating the following org source block should color the '@' tag blue.

```
#+TITLE: Tag face
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defface org-tag-face
  '((nil :foreground "blue" :background "#f7f7f7"))
  "org tag face")
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 '((":\\(@[^\:]+\\):" (1 'org-tag-face))))
#+END_SRC

* test           :@tst:
* test2          :tst:
```

After evaluating, revert the buffer or call `font-lock-flush` and `font-lock-ensure` to update font-locking.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `:@tag1:@tag2:@tag3:`, it applies the face for alternative @tags.

Comment: @Jason just adjust the regex

Comment: Seems harder than expected. Because Emacs doesn't support look-ahead and look-behind regex rules that don't consume characters. With these rules the regex would be something like this: `(?<=:)(@[^:]+)(?=:)`.

Comment: you don't need lookaheads -- simply match sequences starting with `:@` and ending with `:` before end of line